# Ckeditor in Small IFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe, ckeditor, fckeditor

I place the editor in a small iframe (the size is just as big as the editor).In FCkeditor 2.x,the dialog will float in the parent.But in new Ckeditor,It is just float in the iframe ,that cannot displayed completely.

How can I make the dialog float in the parent just like 2.x?
tanks
[image: The dialog is in the iframe,not in the parent]

Comment: I'm not sure you can. I think in FCKEditor, the dialogs were real new browser windows, while in CKEditor, they are inline dialogs. Interested to see whether a solution comes up

Comment: There is inline dialog in last version of Fckeditor and it works well in iframe

Answer (score 2):

It would seem that we are not able to have the dialogs appear outside of an `Iframe`.

http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/8190

Comment: Yeah,I this is my question.But I cannot figure out why they reject to support this feature that old version had.